# How to force WF4 State Machine workflow service to throw on unexpected message name?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice, workflow-services

I have a *.xamlx workflow service running in IIS and have State1, State2 and State3.

```
Trigger T1 (State 1 -> State 2) listens to "Start" message on Receive Activity.
Trigger T2 (State 2 -> State 3) listens to "Proceed" message on Receive Activity.
```

The problem I have is that i expect something like InvalidOperationException when my state machine is in State 1 and "Proceed" message is coming. However, it looks like it is just awaiting in queue and fails with timeout exception.

How do I get an expected behavior here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just pasting here an answer I got from [Jim Carley - MSFT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/jim%20carley%20-%20msft/?ws=usercard-mini) at MSDN forums so that it doesn't disappear after some years.

> Alexander,
>
> You are running into a situation where the workflow has both "protocol
>   bookmarks" and "non-protocol bookmarks". "Protocol bookmarks" are
>   created by the messaging activities (e.g Receive). "Non-protocol
>   bookmarks" are bookmarks that are unrelated to messaging activities.
>   And State activities create non-protocol bookmarks internally.
>
> This issue was reported when using "Pick" also -
>   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/275f7817-1ec7-433c-89ba-fe48afd1dae8/wf4-wcf-send-message-at-wrong-time?forum=wfprerelease
>
> Here is an excerpt from my explanation on that thread:
>
> The root cause of the difference in behavior (timeout) when using a
>   Pick or State activity to encapsulate the Receive for OperationB is
>   that Pick and State activities create internal bookmarks that are
>   unrelated to the bookmarks created by Receive activities.
>
> The bookmarks created by Receive activities (let’s call them “protocol
>   bookmarks”) are treated in a special way in order to preserve the
>   messaging protocol implemented by the workflow service.
>
> Imagine a scenario where the service has the messaging “protocol” of
>   Operation1 followed by Operation2:
>
> Receive(Operation1)
>
> SendReply(Operation1)
>
> DoSomeOtherWork
>
> Receive(Operation2)
>
> SendReply(Operation2)
>
> If DoSomeOtherWork has asynchronous operations that may cause the
>   workflow instance to go idle, they are going to create non-protocol
>   bookmarks. These bookmarks will get resumed thru some other means,
>   outside of the messaging protocol for the workflow service.
>
> So it is possible for Operation1 to complete and for the client to
>   send Operation2 before DoSomeOtherWork is complete. We don’t want to
>   reject Operation2 immediately. Instead, we hang onto the Operation2
>   message in hopes that the work being done by DoSomeOtherWork completes
>   and the bookmark associated with that work gets resumed. Once
>   DoSomeOtherWork completes, the protocol bookmark for
>   Receive(Operation2) will get created and now the message from the
>   client can successfully get processed.
>
> While DoSomeOtherWork is still outstanding, the message for Operation
>   2 is received. It discovers that there is no protocol bookmark for
>   Operation2. We then check to see if there are any non-protocol
>   bookmarks outstanding for the instance. If there are (as is the case
>   when DoSomeOtherWork is still outstanding), we hang on to the message.
>   But if there are no other non-protocol bookmarks, we immediately
>   reject the message as being out of order.
>
> Starting in .NET 4.6, there is an AppSetting that you can specify in
>   the web.config file of your service that controls how non-protocol
>   bookmarks and out-of-order messages are dealt with. To configure the
>   AppSetting, add this to your web.config file:
>
> The value of this "FilterResumeTimeoutInSeconds" specifies the length
>   of time (in seconds) the workflow runtime hangs on to an out-of-order
>   message before it times out. The default value is 60. A value of 0
>   specifies that it should not wait at all and reject out-of-order
>   message with fault with the text:
>
> Operation '' on service instance with 
>   identifier '' cannot be performed at this 
>   time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the correct
>   order  and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery
>   guarantees.
>
> If the value is greater than 0, then you will still get a timeout
>   exception after the specified time expires.
>
> Again, this new AppSetting is available starting in .NET 4.6. And this
>   all assumes that BufferedReceive is NOT being used.
>
> This is also documented here:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-net-framework-4-6.aspx?PageIndex=2